# NoReverseMatch at/ something wrong with url with slug

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm getting `NoReverseMatch at /`:

> Reverse for 'category' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P[\w\-]+)/$']

I'm not sure where it went wrong. I know where it's causing but I don't know why. This url is causing the error:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

and error is coming from this index.html

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'category' category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with my views.py but just in case I will post it here

```
    #for front page

def index(request):
        """This view return index page. In index page, there is thread list.
        And thread list can be sorted by score, number of comment, date, title using paging.
        GET parameters are 'sort' and 'page'. 'sort' is sorting methods. 'page' is number of page.
        :param request: Django request object
        :return: Thread list page
        """

        categories = Category.objects.all()

        try:
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
        except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

        if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                thread_list = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
        else:
                thread_list = Post.objects.all()
                thread_list = sorted(thread_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

        paginator = Paginator(thread_list, 30)

        try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
                "categories":categories
        }
        return render(request, "main/index.html", context)

#for single-post page
def post(request, slug):
        single_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        single_post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        single_post.save()      # and save it
        context_dict = {
            'single_post' :single_post,
        }

        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
#for category page
def category(request, category_name_slug):
    try:

                category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
    except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

    if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                thread_list = Post.objects.filter(category=category).order_by("-pub_date")
    else:
                thread_list = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
                thread_list = sorted(thread_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

    paginator = Paginator(thread_list, 30)

    try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
                "categories":category,
              "cat_name_slug":category_name_slug,
        }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note is that you have an *empty slug*:

> Reverse for 'category' with arguments **'(u'',)'** and keyword arguments '{}' not found

One problem is how you define the `categories` - [`.all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) is a method, *call it*:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
                             HERE^
```

Also, you should check that your categories have non-empty slugs generated.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand ya, I called categories inside index.html. I don't think this is causing the problem?or is it?

Comment: @haloyoba in other words, replace `categories = Category.objects.all` with `categories = Category.objects.all()` and see if it helps.

Comment: Oh, silly mistake there. I still get the same error...hmm... I think it's coming from slug in url. when I do without url I get all the name of categories

Comment: @haloyoba okay, could you show how your slugs are generated - there is likely a problem there and slugs are set to empty.

Comment: Hello I just edited my views.py, did I do this part right inside index.html <a href="{% url 'category' category.slug %}">, my best guess is I didn't put the naming in url right.......(srry this is my first project in django

Comment: is this because I didn't provide def absollute url? maybe